# User and Admin Logins Redirects in Android Using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, admin

I have been trying to login via different accounts in android, i am not able to have different redirects for different users. Mainly i cant fetch users' email from authentication as a condition so that i can have different redirects. trying different steps from a while now. Can someone help?

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful() == true) {

                        if(email.equals("dummy@gmail.com"))
                        {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,RegisterActivity.class));
                        }
                        else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                        }

                    } else if (task.isSuccessful() == false) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid emailid or password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        passwordUser.getText().clear();
                        emailUser.getText().clear();
                        emailUser.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only firebase can't help you to determine role of user. You need to integrate firebase auth with your database to determine role of user.

For Accessing email of logged in user please follow this code

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
// Name, email address, and profile photo Url
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String email = user.getEmail();
Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

// Check if user's email is verified
boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

// The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
// authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
// FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
String uid = user.getUid();
}
```